# 2D-position of circle, for rounding an angle in OpenSCAD

Tags: geometry, rounding, angle, openscad

I know the following:

- P (x,y coordinates).
- A1 and A2 (angles in degrees)
- R (radius of circle).

[image: ... See attached image.]

Now I need to calculate a center for the green circle, as to make it 'tangentize?' the two blue lines (it will later be minkowski'ed with other shapes to form a point of a rounded triangle).

Any help will be appreciated!

My code for the depicted example:

```
//KNOWNS
P=[-3.0,1.0,0.0];
A1=60; A2=-5;
R=5;

//UNKNOWN
SECRET_CALCULATION = [8.2,4.3,0];//???

//ILLUSTRATION
C0=[0,0,0,1]; C1=[0,1,1,0.3]; C2=[0,1,0,0.4]; C3=[1,0,0,0.4];//Colors
translate(P){
    color(C1) rotate(A1) translate([0,-0.5,0]) square([250,1],0);
    color(C1) rotate(A2) translate([0,-0.5,0]) square([250,1],0);
    color(C2) translate(SECRET_CALCULATION) circle(R);
}


//EXPLANATIONS
color(C0) translate(P) {
    translate(SECRET_CALCULATION){
        translate([0,-0.2,0]) square([R,0.4],0);
        translate([R+1,0,0]) rotate(-90) text(str("R:",R),halign="center",valign="top",0.75);
        translate([0,0.2,0]) text("[x?,y?,0]",halign="center",valign="bottom",0.75);
    }
    rotate(((A1-A2)/2)-90) translate([0,-1,0]) text(str("P: ",P),halign="center",valign="top",0.75);
    rotate(A1) text(str("    A1: ",A1,"°"),halign="left",valign="center",0.75);
    rotate(A2) text(str("    A2: ",A2,"°"),halign="left",valign="center",0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center of circle lies at the bisector of rays A1 and A2. So we can find direction for this bisector as

```
B = (A1 + A2) / 2        = 27.5 here
```

(but don't forget about angle normalization - angle `-5` might be represented as `355` and so on)

And angle between bisector and `A1` or `A2` is

```
D = (A1 - A2) / 2         = 32.5 here
```

We can see that points `C(enter)-T(angentpoint)-P` form right triangle with relation

```
L (P-C, DistAlongBisector) = R / Sin(D)
```

So we can find center coordinates as

```
 C.X = P.X + Cos(B) * L
 C.Y = P.Y + Sin(B) * L
```

Quick hand-check gives

```
L=5/Sin(32.5)=9.3
C.X = -3 + Cos(27.5)*9.3 = 5.24
C.Y = 1 + Sin(27.5)*9.3 = 5.3
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but using this calculation, I get `[5.254,5.296]` as circles center-point ... which is not correct. Values should be closer to  `[8.2,4.3]` (which is an estimation based on the visual representation) :(

Comment: [8.2,4.3] is not coordinate! It is difference with point P! Note `Cos(27.5)*9.3 = 8.24   Sin(27.5)*9.3 = 4.3`

Comment: Sorry. You are right!
I'll accept your answer ... Thank you!